# Eclipse / SWT: How to monitor UI event queue?

Tags: eclipse, swt

Doing a lot of thread cleanup in a multi threaded eclipse rcp application. Its got a lot of non UI related actions taking place on the UI thread due to haphazard coding in the past (me included, i'll admit it).

We've been doing a ton of cleanup and proper threading. I really want to monitor the UI runnable queue to see whats going on to ensure I'm not missing things.

Any recommendations on how to monitor the UISynchronizer.messageCount / RunnableLock[] as I am using the appliction?

Comment: I'm really curious to see a solution to this issue. Seems interesting.

Comment: Get the source plugin and modify it!